# operator '.' cannot be applied to lambda expression

Tags: json, linq, lambda

I'm trying to create linq lambda expression to return customer whose first or last name starts with specific letters. However i get the error on .select saying that:

operator '.' cannot be applied to lambda expression.

```
public JsonResult GetCust(string term) 
{ 
    var data = context.Customers
          .Where((dr => dr.First.StartsWith(term) == true) || (dr => dr.Last.StartsWith(term) == true))
          .Select(dr => new { Name=String.Concat(dr.First, dr.Last), Adrs = dr.Street, value = dr.CustID }) 
          .Take(10); 
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Any idea how can I return needed data?

Comment: ops...
It seems I simply forgot to type in another closing bracket in .where
Should be:
 .Where((dr => dr.First.StartsWith(term) == true) || (dr => dr.Last.StartsWith(term) == true)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line:

```
.Where((dr => dr.First.StartsWith(term) == true) || (dr => dr.Last.StartsWith(term) == true))
```

you are using the ||-Operator on two lambda-expressions.

The Where-Clause should more look like this:

```
.Where(dr => dr.First.StartsWith(term) || dr.Last.StartsWith(term))
```

Comment: As I found out few minutes after posting a question- this is it- without unnecessary brackets in my expression.